# Terminology for describing a kind of server

Tags: terminology, databases

What is the adjective used to describe the fact that a server keep track of queries made by a user. I take the example of a database server.

Comment: In which way is this a computer *science* question? What does "keep track" mean here? What kind of requests?

Comment: It may be called spying ... depending on context.

Comment: [Persisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a server would be [stateful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_%28computer_science%29) rather than stateless: roughly speaking, stateful means that it keeps some information, possibly partial information, on past queries.  If you are looking for a single word to capture the idea that the server stores a complete record of all past queries, in their entirety, I don't know of a single word that does that -- so just use a sentence to describe what you're talking about.

Comment: But, would you call it stateful if it is keeping track of history on the user's machine, as is done on the web with cookies.

Comment: @babou, no.  If there's no state stored on the server, the server is stateless..  The standard terminology is exactly that cookies allow the server to be stateless (e.g., by offloading state onto the client).  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-say-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol.  Anyway, we've gotten a bit off-track from the original question.

Comment: Sorry for going astray ... I was just wondering, given that it is a way of "integrating" the client in the server, if there was a specific name (other than cookies).Another point is that the server could be stateful or stateless in other functionalities than answering user requests. But I do tend to go astray and confuse issues.